Excessive DNS lookups in DataDog APM traces
We are using Datadog for tracing by including the dd-trace library in our NodeJS microservices.
We started to notice strange DNS lookups in our traces. These lookups show the IP address of the kubernetes node where the service pod is located. We don't do any DNS lookups in the service code.
I am attaching a screenshot with 3 DNS lookups:
Image with 3 DNS lookups
As you can see in the trace there are no requests to other services except to MySQL, but it has different IP address and located on different instance.
What are these DNS lookups? It does not look normal for me... May it be the dd-trace library itself attempting to resolve current host name to the ip address?
